# Django projects deploy for local computers

Tags: django, web-deployment, wampserver

Is there any way to deploy "Django" projects for local computers ?? like "Put Online" in WAMP.

Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a local development server you can use when creating your applications. You run it via the command [`python manage.py runserver`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port):

> (Runserver) starts a lightweight development Web server on the local machine. By default, the server runs on port 8000 on the IP address 127.0.0.1. You can pass in an IP address and port number explicitly.

Be wary that this isn't suitable for any sort of production code:

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)